# Wordpress plugin Invalid header error

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a `Wordpress` site hosted by `Parallels` and uploaded via the plex panel.

When I am installing a new `plugin`, first, I am notified that the `plugin` has been successfully installed.

But when I click on `Activate`, I get an error message saying:

```
"The plugin does not have a valid header."
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, and it does on every `Wordpress plugin` that I try to install.

When I try to upload the plugin manually by browsing for a folder and clicking upload, I get a different error message:

```
"Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/12. Is its parent directory writable by the server?"
```

These two errors are really puzzling and neither myself or my client can install any plugins.

**P.s.  The above features work fine on the local server - it is just the development server that I am having issues.**

Comment: U need to add proper write permissions for certain folders like plugins, so that you can install plugins via admin. Change permission to 775 and this should work for you

Answer (score 6):

Do you have FTP access to the site? "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/12" says to me that the permissions are not set right on your wp-content folder. Set it to 755, or, if you're feeling brave, 777 (though there are security concerns there). Once the permissions are set, try reinstalling again.

Answer (score 0):

When plugin key "$plugin" doesn't match with plugin files then wordpress generate this error on activation time.

You can check the code by following code

```
file path Error is generating from
wp-admin/includes/plugin.php 
line number 920

//use following code to check the keys. 
echo $plugin;
print_r($installed_plugins);
```